# TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string at Function.use

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, routes

I'm new to Node and ExpressJs development, however, I cannot import a module router created by me as an exercise.

It gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Router.use () requires a middleware function but got a string
     at Function.use
```

I have already tried the module.exports solution, but it doesn't work. The initialize function also fails.

Here are the versions I am working with:
Node version: v10.19.0
Express version: 4.17.2

Index.js

```
    const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ProgettoRouting = require("./routing/ProgettoRouting");

app.use("view engine","jade");
app.use(express.static("public"));
//Codifica dati json con questo middlware senza uso
//del pacchetto npm Body Parser
app.use(express.json());

//Con questo milldelware Importiamo il Router Dati
//dove risiedono le funzionalità del progetto
app.use('/route', ProgettoRouting);

//app.use(app.ProgettoRouting);
//ProgettoRouting.initialize(app);

app.listen(3000, () => {console.log("Server in ascolto sulla porta 3000")});
```

ProgettoRouting.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


router.post("/",(res,req) => {
    let firstName = req.body.nome;
    let lastName = req.body.cognome;
    let message = {nome: firstName, cognome: lastName};
    res.render("index",message);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

`app.set("view engine","jade");`

instead of

`app.use("view engine","jade");`

as you're intending to set the `view-engine` property to `jade`, not setting up a middleware.

Comment: Cabbage !! I didn't notice, I thought I wrote set instead of use
You're right, what a bad mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Replace This Line

```
app.use("view engine","jade");
```

To

```
app.set("view engine","jade");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answer that was given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.